# Custom error page ,when Http error occured without changing url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to show custom error page ,when Http error occured without changing url.

When Http error occured then how to show customer custom error page without routing to another Url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below method will not use a redirect - it will return your custom error + correct httpstatus code as an immediate response to the client, by catching the error in the application_error method and then choosing what to return within the same response, removing the need to redirect.

Create an ErrorController - this allows you to tailor your end-user error pages and status codes.:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UnauthorisedRequest()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return View();
    }

    //Any other errors you want to specifically handle here.

    public ActionResult CatchAllUrls()
    {
        //throwing an exception here pushes the error through the Application_Error method for centralised handling/logging
        throw new HttpException(404, "The requested url " + Request.Url.ToString() + " was not found");
    }
}
```

Add a route to catch all urls to the end of your route config - this captures all 404's that are not already caught by matching existing routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("CatchAllUrls", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "CatchAllUrls" });
```

In your global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        //Error logging omitted

        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        IController errorController = new Controllers.ErrorController();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("area", "");
        routeData.Values.Add("ex", exception);

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            //this is a basic exampe of how you can choose to handle your errors based on http status codes.
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    Response.Clear();

                    // page not found
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

                    Server.ClearError();
                    // Call the controller with the route
                    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));

                    break;
                case 500:
                    // server error
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");

                    Server.ClearError();
                    // Call the controller with the route
                    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
                    break;
                 case 403:
                    // server error
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "UnauthorisedRequest");

                    Server.ClearError();
                    // Call the controller with the route
                    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
                    break;
                 //add cases for other http errors you want to handle, otherwise HTTP500 will be returned as the default.
                default:
                    // server error
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");

                    Server.ClearError();
                    // Call the controller with the route
                    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
                    break;
            }
        }
        //All other exceptions should result in a 500 error as they are issues with unhandled exceptions in the code
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");
            Server.ClearError();
            // Call the controller with the route
            errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution! Thanks, Carl!

Answer (score 1):

Add following `<customErrors>` tag in the web.config that helps you to redirect to the NotFound action method of Error controller if the system fails to find the requested url (status code 404) and redirects to ServerError action method of error controller if the system fires an internal server error (status code 500)

```
<!--<Redirect to error page>-->
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ServerError">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
<!--</Redirect to error page>-->
```

You have to create an Error controller that contains ServerError and NotFound action method that renders the related view to display the proper message to the user.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

## **Edit 2:**

For remain the same url while custom error occurs, you need to install **Magical Unicorn Mvc Error Toolkit 2.2.2** nuget package.

you can follow the following steps to work with:

1. Open solution in visual studio
2. Go to `Tools` menu and select `Nuget Package Manager`
3. Select `Package Manager Console` from sub menu
4. Write `PM> Install-Package MagicalUnicorn.MvcErrorToolkit` in Package Manager Console

you can [visit here for more info](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MagicalUnicorn.MvcErrorToolkit/) about the nuget package

It will install the nuget package that will work as per your requirement.

Comment: In this case my url is changing,but i want that my url of customer entered page remain same and customer has show customize error page

Comment: see my Edit2 for your query