# Show a custom 403 error page in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-error-pages

I want to show a custom 403 page in my ASP.NET MVC 2 application. I added following to my config file:

```xml
<httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/403.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I am still seeing the default ASP.NET 403 error page. What's wrong?

[image: the default ASP.NET 403 error page]

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844627/custom-error-page-when-http-error-occured-without-changing-url/25844739#25844739

Comment: @HirenKagrana Tried. Doesn't works for me. Getting 500 and application doesn't starts. Also I don't have any specific requirement like redirecting. I just want a custom error page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add below markup in web.config:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/error">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="/error/badrequest" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/error/forbidden" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/notfound" />
  <error statusCode="414" redirect="/error/urltoolong" />
  <error statusCode="503" redirect="/error/serviceunavailable" />
</customErrors>
```

Add a view model named ErrorInfo with below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Gunaatita.ViewModel
{
    public class ErrorInfo
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create a controller name ErrorController with below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Gunaatita.ViewModel;

namespace Gunaatita.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "An Error Has Occured";
            errorInfo.Description = "An unexpected error occured on our website. The website administrator has been notified.";
            return PartialView(errorInfo);
        }
        public ActionResult BadRequest()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "Bad Request";
            errorInfo.Description = "The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.";
            return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
        }
        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.";
            errorInfo.Description = "The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.";
            return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
        }

        public ActionResult Forbidden()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "403 Forbidden";
            errorInfo.Description = "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access [directory] on this server.";
            return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
        }
        public ActionResult URLTooLong()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "URL Too Long";
            errorInfo.Description = "The requested URL is too large to process. That’s all we know.";
            return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
        }
        public ActionResult ServiceUnavailable()
        {
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.Message = "Service Unavailable";
            errorInfo.Description = "Our apologies for the temporary inconvenience. This is due to overloading or maintenance of the server.";
            return PartialView("Error", errorInfo);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And update \Views\Shared\Error.cshtml with below markup:

```
@model Gunaatita.ViewModel.ErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Problem";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSite.cshtml";
}

<div class="middle-container">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/thankyou.css">
    <!--- middle Container ---->

    <div class="middle-container">
        <div class="paddings thankyou-section" data-moduleid="2050" id="ContactUsPane">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <h1>@Model.Message</h1>
                <p>@Model.Description</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <h1>An Error Has Occured</h1>
                <p>An unexpected error occured on our website. The website administrator has been notified.</p>
            }

            <p><a href="/" class="btn-read-more">Go To Home Page</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- middle Container ---->

</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying this but `ErrorInfo` is not valid type? Am I missing some refernce?

Comment: I have just updated the answer with ErrorInfo Class. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

By default MVC template implements HandleErrorAttribute att. We can find this in the Global.asax  (or for MVC4 in the App_Start\FilterConfig.cs)

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)   {
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());  
   }
```

HandleErrorAttribute redirects user to the default Error page if CustomErrors is turned ON in   web.config.

To enable custom error handling  by HandleErrorAttribute filter, we need to add customErrors element in  system.web section of the application's Web.config as shown below:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml" />
</system.web>
```

Syntax :

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url"   mode="On | Off | RemoteOnly"> 
</customErrors>
```

We can have separate views also to redirect User to the specific view based on the error status codes, as shown below:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error code="404" path="~/Views/Shared/NotFound.cshtml" /> 
    <error code="500" path="~/Views/Shared/InternalServerError.cshtml" /> 
</customErrors>
```

Now lets see how HandleErrorAttribute redirects user to default Error.cshtml view. To test this, lets throw an exception from Index action of Login Controller as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index()  {  
    throw new ApplicationException("Error");  
    //return View();  
}
```

We will see the default output from Errors.cshtml in the Shared folder of a default MVC project which will  return a correct 500 status message but where is our Stack Trace??

Now to capture Stack Trace we need to do couple of modifications in Error.cshtml, as shown below:

```
 @model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
    <hgroup>
      <div class="container">
                <h1 class="row btn-danger">Error.</h1>
    @{
                    if (Request.IsLocal)
                    {
                        if (@Model != null && @Model.Exception != null)
                        {
                            <div class="well row">

                                <h4> Controller: @Model.ControllerName</h4>
                                <h4> Action: @Model.ActionName</h4>
                                <h4> Exception: @Model.Exception.Message</h4>
                                <h5>
                                    Stack Trace: @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                                </h5>
                            </div>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <h4>Exception is Null</h4>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="well row">
                            <h4>An unexpected error occurred on our website. The website administrator has been notified.</h4>
                            <br />
                            <h5>For any further help please visit <a href="http://abcd.com/"> here</a>. You can also email us anytime at support@abcd.com or call us at (xxx) xxx-xxxx.</h5>
                        </div>
                    }

                }
    </div>
    </hgroup>
```

This change ensure that we see detailed stack trace.

Try this approach and see.

Answer (score 0):

Many good suggestions here; for me, it was occurring under visual studio and visual studio started a different web project into the same port as my web project was specified to load in it's config, so it was just refreshing the error on my other projet (which doesn't have a global.asax) no matter what change I made to the second web project.

The underlying issue turned out to be that my other site had the same port configured in visual studio so it kept loading first due to the solution project order and using up the port.  I changed it to another port and the issue went away.