# How to redirect unauthorized users with ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to know how to redirect users. I have a Controller Index() and I want only users with the role "Student" can enter there! So I use

```
[Authorize(Roles="Student")]
```

I wonder how can I redirect users who do not have this role to the homepage

Comment: Check out blowdarts answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### MVC5 (and older):

You can do this by changing the `loginUrl` attribute on your **web.config**. Change it to the desired route:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

### MVC6:

In MVC6 you can try this (inside the `Startup.cs`):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");
    });
}
```

Comment: In MVC 6, the web.config don't exist!

Comment: Thanks Fabrice ! What library should I install? because PathString and CookieAuthenticationOptions aren't reconize !

Comment: I think both namespaces are from `Microsoft.Owin`.

Comment: Okay thanks, my visual studio have some bugs... And do you know the attribut to modify the error Path ? for the moment if my user has don't access ASP redirect my user to "Account/AccessDenied" !

Comment: Yes @Clowining, its in the Startup.cs too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421164/mvc-6-404-not-found
Please mark it as Answered if it answered your question. By the way, I'm Fabric**io** not Fabric**e** :P

Comment: Oh thanks you FabricIO :p ! But my problem it's not resvoled ! I think i must to override or create a new [Authorize] Tag ! Do you have an idea to make this in MVC 6? :)

Comment: You don't need to create a new [Authorize] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method floating around that works for MVC5.  I assume it would work for MVC6 as well.
Within your Controller, create a Custom Auth method like so.

```
    public class YourCustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // If they are authorized, handle accordingly
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise redirect to your specific authorized area
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/YourController/Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your data annotations to

```
[YourCustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
     // Omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Did you try to use session for this?

I'm guessing you have login page then after login classify the session ASAP

then simple If condition will do.

```
<%If Session("userRole")="Student" Then%>
  This is the text version of the page
<%Else%>
  Response.Redirect("notavailablepage.html")
<%End If%>
```

Comment: *NEVER* use Session for security purposes.  It's insecure, and has different rules than authentication and authorization.  On top of that, it's unreliable since session resets whenever the application pool does.