# asp.net Core MVC 6 A different home page for authorized users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project with Identity 3.0. I have setup a dynamic menu which also works and displays a different menu list depending on what role you are in.

I would like Authorized users to have different home page. If you are UnAuthorized you should see "/Home/Index" as per normal.

If you are Authorized (logged in as a user and it remembers you..) you should always be directed to a different home page for Authorized users... say "/Scheduling/Index".

I have set an AuthorizeFilter

```
           services.AddMvc(setup =>
        {
            setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
        });
```

so unless you are Authorized you get sent to the login page if you are try an access any controller without the:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

at the start... eg HomeController has this at the start...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598319/how-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-with-asp-net-mvc-6?lq=1) on Stackoverflow and tried it in the StartUp class but it doesnt work.

```
            services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Scheduler/Index");
        });
```

How can I have two different home pages depending on whether the user is logged in or not logged in?

Answer (score 3):

You have (at least) two ways:

**1) Return different view names** from your 'Index' action (depending on user status):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index()
{
     // code for both (anonymous and authorized) users
     ...

     var shouldShowOtherHomePage = ... // check anything you want, even specific roles
     return View(shouldShowOtherHomePage ? "AuthorizedIndex" ? "Index", myModel);
}
```

This one is good when your `Index` method have no "heavy" logic, different for anonymous/authorized users, and you will not have two "branches" of code inside one method.

**2) Redirect authorized users to other action** from `Index`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var shouldShowOtherHomePage = ...
    if (shouldShowOtherHomePage) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AuthorizedIndex", "OtherController");
    }

    // code for anonymous users
    ....
}
```

Use this option when you don't want to mix two logic flows inside one method, or your actions are in different controllers.

Comment: Hi @Dimitry and others.. is there a way to do this just from the StartUp.cs class using filters etc. I would rather have it in the Startup if possible

Comment: You can use [Action filters](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#action-filters) with action/controller-specific logic or [create own Middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#writing-middleware) if you have url-specific logic (for example redirect user to other URL based on current URL and some other conditions) and place in before Mvc middleware. Both are configured in `Startup.cs`