# redirect to custom "access denied" page for ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I writing an ASP.NET Core 1.0 website that uses Windows Authentication.  I have implemented Authorization and that is working as expected.  Currently, when Authentication fails for a given user, a generic "HTTP 403" error page is shown.

[image]

How can I configure ASP.NET Core so that it redirects to my own custom "access denied" page?

I tried the approach outlined in this article, but it didn't work for me (maybe because I'm using Windows Auth instead of Forms Auth?)
[How to redirect unauthorized users with ASP.NET MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598319/how-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-with-asp-net-mvc-6)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [the status code pages middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html#configuring-status-code-pages).

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
  if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
  {
     // your redirect
  }
});
```

You can also choose more generic approach via `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`. The middleware can handle redirects (with either relative or absolute URL paths), passing the status code as part of the URL. For example the following will redirect to `~/errors/403` for 403 error:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/errors/{0}");
```