# UseStatusCodePages vs UseStatusCodeWithReExecute issues

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, model-view-controller

### SOLVED: See edit at the bottom of the post.

I have successfully set up Middleware to UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute().  The application leverages against Active Directory to Authenticate and Authorize.

Using Dotnet Core 3.0; MVC

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {


            if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/StatusCode", "?statusCode={0}");
                //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("AccessDenied");
                app.UseStatusCodePages();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
        }
```

*Note: the Home controller on the ReExecute has an Authorize attribute (no Roles specified), but the "StatusCode" Action has an AllowAnonymous attribute on it.*

In my controller, I have also added an "Authorize" attribute, along with a specific `[Authorize(Role="Admin")]` on the specific action.

When type type in a bogus URL, I am successfully getting my Custom 404 Error Page.

What I am having difficulty with is the 403 errors when I try to access the Controller/Action with the Authorization attribute attached.  If I simply use UseStatusCodePages(), I get the default `Status Code: 403; Forbidden` on a blank page, as well as the basic pages on the 404 status code.

If I use UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirect(), I get an odd '**localhost** redirected you too many times` error. [See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZeI0.png)  It suggests clearing cookies, and I did, but to no avail.

If I use UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(), the 404 works as expected (custom error page), but the 403 defaults to the "generic" Access-Denied page, instead of the custom page, or even the regular StatusCodePage.

[Generic Access Denied Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzWd4.png)

I can see why the ReExecute wouldn't work since it is trying to re-execute against an action that the user is not authorized to execute.

I am not as concerned about the 401 since IIS already has a corporate custom page for 401 Unauthenticated errors.

The customer would like a custom page for Access-Denied page to inform the end-user of whom to contact if they feel that they should have access to a particular part of the application.

I have searched for any articles on this, but they all seem to only address the 404 page.  Any help would be appreciated.

==================

## EDIT: SOLVED

Thanks to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492160/redirect-to-custom-access-denied-page-for-asp-net-core), I changed the following section of the Configure to specifically handle the 403 and I now get the custom Access Denied Page for 403 thanks to a Redirect, but the Re-Execute for other status codes.

```
 . . . 
            if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => { 
                if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403) {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/StatusCode?statusCode=403");
                }
            });
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/StatusCode", "?statusCode={0}");

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
 . . .
```