# ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core for my new REST API project after using regular ASP.NET Web API for many years. I don't see any good way to handle exceptions in ASP.NET Core Web API. I tried to implement an exception handling filter/attribute:

```
public class ErrorHandlingFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        HandleExceptionAsync(context);
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    private static void HandleExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception;

        if (exception is MyNotFoundException)
            SetExceptionResult(context, exception, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        else if (exception is MyUnauthorizedException)
            SetExceptionResult(context, exception, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        else if (exception is MyException)
            SetExceptionResult(context, exception, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        else
            SetExceptionResult(context, exception, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    private static void SetExceptionResult(
        ExceptionContext context, 
        Exception exception, 
        HttpStatusCode code)
    {
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new ApiResponse(exception))
        {
            StatusCode = (int)code
        };
    }
}
```

And here is my Startup filter registration:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizationFilter());
    options.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter());
});
```

The issue I was having is that when an exception occurs in my `AuthorizationFilter` it's not being handled by `ErrorHandlingFilter`. I was expecting it to be caught there just like it worked with the old ASP.NET Web API.

So how can I catch all application exceptions as well as any exceptions from Action Filters?

Comment: Have you tried `UseExceptionHandler` middleware?

Comment: Just as an option, try handling `NotFound` without throwing exceptions. NuGet package like https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult would help here.

Comment: @AlexKlaus it's way too much noise in code.. I would never recommend it to anyone.

Answer (score 757, accepted):

## Global Exception Handler | ASP.NET 8+

Implement interface [IExceptionHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.iexceptionhandler?view=aspnetcore-8.0). You can inject logger and other dependencies in constructor.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;

class MyExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
        HttpContext context, 
        Exception exception, 
        CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        // Your response object
        var error = new { message = exception.Message };
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(error, cancellation);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Once you have your IExceptionHandler implementation, simply register this middleware:

```
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<MyExceptionHandler>();

app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

- You can add multiple IExceptionHandler implementations, and they will be called in the order of registration.
- Return `true` from `TryHandleAsync` if exception is handled, or return `false` and it will be passed to the next handler.

Comment: I have been beating my head against the desk trying to get a custom middleware to work today, and it works basically the same way (I'm using it to manage unit of work/transaction for a request). The problem I'm facing is that raised exceptions in 'next' are not caught in the middleware. As you can imagine, this is problematic. What am I doing wrong/missing? Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: @brappleye3 first thought - make sure you `await` all your async calls e.g. `await context.SaveChangesAsync();`. It's hard to guess without seeing the code. I'd take a look if you post your question with details.

Comment: I typically do a mix of both middleware and `IExceptionFilter`. The filter handles the controller errors directly, and I use the middleware for a more "low level" handling.
 As a hint, if someone needs to execute code by exception type in the global handler, to make it more "readable" feel free to give a look at a small library I made just for that: https://medium.com/@nogravity00/asp-net-core-mvc-and-exception-handling-f0da1c820d4a

Comment: @brappleye3 @Andrei I'm having this same problem. I've used the code above for the middleware and registered it. Then I'm making an api call that just throws notimplemented. I can break on `await next(context);` but the break on `await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);`. Inspecting the context, the response has a 200 code. I'm a bit lost as to why as the exception has been thrown but not caught?

Shouldn't this error be trapped here?

Comment: @brappleye3 - I figured out what the problem was. I was just registering the  middleware in the wrong place in the Startup.cs class. I moved `app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();` to just before `app.UseStaticFiles();`. The exception seems to be caught correctly now. This leads me to believe `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(); app.UseBrowserLink();` Do some internal magic middleware hackery to get the middleware ordering right.

Comment: This seems like it's only good for responding to "caught" exceptions.  How can you have an API call to a bad URL return a JSON response with a 404 code rather than trying to redirect to a custom error page?

Comment: @im1dermike 404 is a bit different as it doesn't raise an exception, but you can always check `context.Response.StatusCode == 404` in exception handling middleware and react as needed. Other than that case, all the uncaught application exceptions will be caught in middleware. Hope it helps.

Comment: `context.Response.StatusCode` at line `await next(context)` is 200 on a bad URL, not 404.

Comment: @im1dermike you should check it after `await next(context);` as MVC should execute first and set the status for you.

Comment: It's still 200 after that line.

Comment: I agree that custom middleware can be very useful but would question using exceptions for NotFound, Unauthorised and BadRequest situations. Why not simply set the status code (using NotFound() etc.) and then handle it in your custom middleware or via UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute? See https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api for more info

Comment: @Andrei When you say 'back to the top of the stack', it sounds as though your dependency graph is rather complex but in a typical application, using the out-of-the-box functionality is simpler and faster. On a high traffic site, you do not want to be throwing thousands of unnecessary exceptions. Yes NotFound() is a controller-only helper but the underlying NotFoundObjectResult can be used from anywhere. [Produces] and [SwaggerResponse] are the recommended methods for indicating return types for Swagger.

Comment: @PaulHiles if all your business logic is in controllers (which is ugly), sure, you can use `NotFound`, `BadRequest` etc. But for production projects even with simple n-tier design with just 3 layers - controllers, services and repositories it will be a huge pain. In some/most cases you can get away from it by returning `null` from service layer. Though `null` is a bad practice. There would be null-checks everywhere. Using exceptions is OK. No null-checks. Performance drop isn't significant and to be honest I'd sacrifice this performance for code-clarity any day.

Comment: @Andrei Hmm OK. If it works for you. I personally find code that raises excepions for every day events, deep within the object graph much less clear. In a typical app, I would say first-level viewmodel validation and unauthorised checks can be handled by action filters or middleware without using exceptions. For 404's, the service can return an object with a status result and then the action can check and return NotFound(). For business level validation, it is more debatable. You can take the same approach as with 404s or use exceptions.

Comment: I think it is also worth reiterating that in response to your original question where you asked about how to capture all application exceptions as well as exceptions from action filters, the simplest way to do this is to use the built-in functionality rather than rolling your own - UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute.

Comment: I use a very simillar approach myself. I would just like to add that this middleware will serialize to json by default `Uppercase` property names, while MVC will do it with `lowercase`. This is easily fixable just by adding a `JsonSerializerSettings` with a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` to the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings)` call.

Comment: It's bad because it's always serializing to JSON, completely ignoring content negotiation.

Comment: So even if you have some other content-type you expect the server to return it will return JSON anyway....

Comment: @Konrad valid point. That's why I said that this example is where you can get started, and not the end result. For 99% of APIs JSON is more than enough. If you feel like this answer isn't good enough, feel free to contribute.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that some behavior has changed since ASP.NET Core 2.1 and the [ApiController] attribute, specifically the model validation errors (Bad Request). For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159755/189429

Comment: There is a built-in middleware that we can use to write a bit less code (it will pretty much be equivalent to this answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55166404/1671558

Comment: Probably I'm suffering the "not invented here" syndrome - but I think your solution is a lot more clear and readable then the "out of the box" solution with UseExceptionHandler()

Comment: I just added an answer with a better way of doing this by relying upon UseExceptionHandler

Comment: it would be good that you at least mention me/my answer in your post. That being said, as you copying anyway, it would be good that you copy fully including [NonAction] annotation otherwise [web API analyses will give a compilation warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/analyzers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#reference-the-analyzer-package)

Comment: that is why you completely change your answer 17 hours after I post mine to also use an ErrorController that extends built-in exception handling. 17 hours before, you had a solution two (equal to @Ilya Chernomordik answer...) although your still preferable solution was using your own middleware. **Those are facts, not opinions**. My answer is based on exception handling built-in functionality as many answers here but shows how can this be done in a better way. We can discuss that in my answer but I guess the advantages are clear to you otherwise you won't have your answer as it is now

Comment: @r.pedrosa it's all because you're da best, the most brilliant software engineer I've ever seen. Thank you so much - every line of your code is pure gold.

Comment: "[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] is needed. Otherwise it may break your Swashbuckle swagger" ah thanks for mentioning this!  Was going to crazy trying to figure out what broke the Swagger documentation.

Comment: @Andrei Hey very generous post.  the MS docs on this make you crazy.  In the previous framework I could populate ReasonPhrase in my custom exception handler then use that in the UI app.  What do I need to do, if you don't mind, to have HttpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase populated with MySpecialString when the request returns to the caller?

Comment: @pdschuller thank you! Yes, this isn't obvious. Try this: `Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Your reason phrase.";` with `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;`

Comment: @Andrei  Yep.  I put that in the ErrorsController and I can send any message I want back to the web service method caller.  Whew!

Comment: @pdschuller sweet!

Comment: Great solution! 
I made something based on your concept. If you wanna replace hte context.Response StatusCode, you can put after before the `await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);`:                 
`if (exception is HttpStatusException httpException)
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)((HttpStatusException)exception).Status;`

Answer (score 128):

There is a built-in middleware for that:

`ASP.NET Core 5` version:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
{
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;
    
    await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new { error = exception.Message });
}));
```

Older versions (they did not have `WriteAsJsonAsync` extension):

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
{
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;
    
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
}));
```

It should do pretty much the same, just a bit less code to write.

**Important:** Remember to add it before `MapControllers` \ `UseMvc` (or `UseRouting` in .Net Core 3) as order is important.

Comment: Does it support DI as an arg to the handler, or would one have to use a service locator pattern within the handler?

Comment: Please check out accepted answer. With that approach you can use DI and you have full control over API response.

Answer (score 35):

Your best bet is to use middleware to achieve logging you're looking for.  You want to put your exception logging in one middleware and then handle your error pages displayed to the user in a different middleware.  That allows separation of logic and follows the design Microsoft has laid out with the 2 middleware components.  Here's a good link to Microsoft's documentation: [Error Handling in ASP.Net Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html)

For your specific example, you may want to use one of the extensions in the [StatusCodePage middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs) or roll your own like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810819/4023606).

You can find an example here for logging exceptions: [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
    // app.UseStatusCodePages();
    // app.UseStatusCodePages(context => context.HttpContext.Response.SendAsync("Handler, status code: " + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode, "text/plain"));
    // app.UseStatusCodePages("text/plain", "Response, status code: {0}");
    // app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/errors/{0}");
    // app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/base/errors/{0}");
    // app.UseStatusCodePages(builder => builder.UseWelcomePage());
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}");  // I use this version

    // Exception handling logging below
    app.UseExceptionHandler();
}
```

If you don't like that specific implementation, then you can also use [ELM Middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Elm/ElmCaptureMiddleware.cs), and here are some examples: [Elm Exception Middleware](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/aspnet-core-diagnostics-middleware-error-handling/)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}");
    // Exception handling logging below
    app.UseElmCapture();
    app.UseElmPage();
}
```

If that doesn't work for your needs, you can always roll your own Middleware component by looking at their implementations of the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware and the ElmMiddleware to grasp the concepts for building your own.

It's important to add the exception handling middleware below the StatusCodePages middleware but above all your other middleware components.  That way your Exception middleware will capture the exception, log it, then allow the request to proceed to the StatusCodePage middleware which will display the friendly error page to the user.

Comment: Note that Elm doesn't persist the logs, and it's recommended to use Serilog or NLog to provide the serialization. See  [ELM logs disappears. Can we persist it to a file or DB?](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/issues/328)

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: @AshleyLee, I question that `UseStatusCodePages` is of use in Web API service implementations. No views or HTML at all, only JSON responses...

Answer (score 35):

The well-accepted answer helped me a lot but I wanted to pass HttpStatusCode in my middleware to manage error status code at runtime.

According to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) I got some idea to do the same. So I merged the Andrei Answer with this. So my final code is below:

1. Base class

```
public class ErrorDetails
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

2. Custom Exception Class Type

```
public class HttpStatusCodeException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; } = @"text/plain";

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message) 
        : base(message)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception inner) 
        : this(statusCode, inner.ToString()) { }

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, JObject errorObject) 
        : this(statusCode, errorObject.ToString())
    {
        this.ContentType = @"application/json";
    }

}
```

3. Custom Exception Middleware

```
public class CustomExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, exceptionObj);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, HttpStatusCodeException exception)
    {
        string result = null;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        if (exception is HttpStatusCodeException)
        {
            result = new ErrorDetails() 
            {
                Message = exception.Message,
                StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode 
            }.ToString();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;
        }
        else
        {
            result = new ErrorDetails() 
            { 
                Message = "Runtime Error",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            }.ToString();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        string result = new ErrorDetails() 
        { 
            Message = exception.Message,
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError 
        }.ToString();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

4. Extension Method

```
public static void ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionMiddleware>();
}
```

5. Configure Method in startup.cs

```
app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();
app.UseMvc();
```

**Now my login method in Account controller :**

```
try
{
    IRepository<UserMaster> obj 
        = new Repository<UserMaster>(_objHeaderCapture, Constants.Tables.UserMaster);
    var result = obj.Get()
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(sb => sb.EmailId.ToLower() == objData.UserName.ToLower() 
            && sb.Password == objData.Password.ToEncrypt() 
            && sb.Status == (int)StatusType.Active)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)//User Found
        return result;
    else // Not Found
        throw new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            "Please check username or password");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Above you can see if i have not found the user then raising the HttpStatusCodeException in which i have passed HttpStatusCode.NotFound status and a custom message 
 In middleware

> catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex)

blocked will be called which will pass control to

> private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context,
> HttpStatusCodeException exception) method

But what if i got runtime error before? For that i have used try catch block which throw exception and will be catched in catch (Exception exceptionObj) block and will pass control to

> Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)

method.
 
I have used a single ErrorDetails class for uniformity.

Comment: Where to put extension method? Unfortunately in the `startup.cs` in `void Configure(IapplicationBuilder app)` I get an error `IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware`. And I added the reference, where `CustomExceptionMiddleware.cs` is.

Comment: you don't want to use exceptions as they slow down your apis. exceptions are very expensive.

Comment: @Inaie, Can't say about that... but it seems you have never got any exception to handle to.. Great work

Comment: Are you sure to use "throw ex;" instead of "throw;" ?

Comment: @LeszekP, i think both will work, though i have not tested it

Comment: I'm a little confused at the point of this answer, you do know the HTTP status code is already on the context right? `context.Response.StatusCode`

Comment: @bytedev, I wanted to throw custom HTTP status code based on equation

Answer (score 21):

To Configure exception handling behavior per exception type you can use Middleware from NuGet packages:

- [Community.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.NewtonsoftJson)
   for `ASP.NET Core 2.0`
- [Community.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Community.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.Mvc) for `ASP.NET Core 2.1+`.

Code sample:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddExceptionHandlingPolicies(options =>
    {
        options.For<InitializationException>().Rethrow();

        options.For<SomeTransientException>().Retry(ro => ro.MaxRetryCount = 2).NextPolicy();

        options.For<SomeBadRequestException>()
        .Response(e => 400)
            .Headers((h, e) => h["X-MyCustomHeader"] = e.Message)
            .WithBody((req,sw, exception) =>
                {
                    byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exception.ToString());
                    return sw.WriteAsync(array, 0, array.Length);
                })
        .NextPolicy();

        // Ensure that all exception types are handled by adding handler for generic exception at the end.
        options.For<Exception>()
        .Log(lo =>
            {
                lo.EventIdFactory = (c, e) => new EventId(123, "UnhandlerException");
                lo.Category = (context, exception) => "MyCategory";
            })
        .Response(null, ResponseAlreadyStartedBehaviour.GoToNextHandler)
            .ClearCacheHeaders()
            .WithObjectResult((r, e) => new { msg = e.Message, path = r.Path })
        .Handled();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandlingPolicies();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Firstly, thanks to Andrei as I've based my solution on his example.

I'm including mine as it's a more complete sample and might save readers some time.

The limitation of Andrei's approach is that doesn't handle logging, capturing potentially useful request variables and content negotiation (it will always return JSON no matter what the client has requested - XML / plain text etc).

My approach is to use an ObjectResult which allows us to use the functionality baked into MVC.

This code also prevents caching of the response.

The error response has been decorated in such a way that it can be serialized by the XML serializer.

```
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult> executor;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private static readonly ActionDescriptor EmptyActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult> executor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.executor = executor;
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, $"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Url: {context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()}. Request Data: " + GetRequestData(context));

            if (context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                throw;
            }

            var routeData = context.GetRouteData() ?? new RouteData();

            ClearCacheHeaders(context.Response);

            var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, EmptyActionDescriptor);

            var result = new ObjectResult(new ErrorResponse("Error processing request. Server error."))
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            };

            await executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, result);
        }
    }

    private static string GetRequestData(HttpContext context)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Any())
        {
            sb.Append("Form variables:");
            foreach (var x in context.Request.Form)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Key={0}, Value={1}<br/>", x.Key, x.Value);
            }
        }

        sb.AppendLine("Method: " + context.Request.Method);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void ClearCacheHeaders(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "-1";
        response.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.ETag);
    }

    [DataContract(Name= "ErrorResponse")]
    public class ErrorResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public ErrorResponse(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs if you want to check the current source code currently and add things from this approach.

Answer (score 10):

First, configure ASP.NET Core 2 `Startup` to re-execute to an error page for any errors from the web server and any unhandled exceptions.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        // Debug config here...
    } else {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }
    // More config...
}
```

Next, define an exception type that will let you throw errors with HTTP status codes.

```
public class HttpException : Exception
{
    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode) { StatusCode = statusCode; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }
}
```

Finally, in your controller for the error page, customize the response based on the reason for the error and whether the response will be seen directly by an end user. This code assumes all API URLs start with `/api/`.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    // Gets the status code from the exception or web server.
    var statusCode = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error is HttpException httpEx ?
        httpEx.StatusCode : (HttpStatusCode)Response.StatusCode;

    // For API errors, responds with just the status code (no page).
    if (HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>().RawTarget.StartsWith("/api/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        return StatusCode((int)statusCode);

    // Creates a view model for a user-friendly error page.
    string text = null;
    switch (statusCode) {
        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound: text = "Page not found."; break;
        // Add more as desired.
    }
    return View("Error", new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, ErrorText = text });
}
```

ASP.NET Core will log the error detail for you to debug with, so a status code may be all you want to provide to a (potentially untrusted) requester. If you want to show more info, you can enhance `HttpException` to provide it. For API errors, you can put JSON-encoded error info in the message body by replacing `return StatusCode...` with `return Json...`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is [the official guideline from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors) covering WebAPI and MVC cases for all versions of .NET.

For Web API it suggests redirecting to a dedicated controller end-point to return [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails). As it may lead to potential exposure in the [OpenAPI spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification) of end-points that aren't meant to be called directly, I'd suggest a simpler solution:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
    {
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;
        var problem = new ProblemDetails { Title = "Critical Error"};
        if (error != null)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                problem.Title = error.Message;
                problem.Detail = error.StackTrace;
            }
            else
                problem.Detail = error.Message;
        }
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(problem);
    }));
    ...
}
```

In this case, we leverage a standard middleware that returns custom details (with a stack trace for dev mode) and avoid creating 'internal' end-points.

P.S. Note that [the official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors) relies on `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` before .NET v3 and since then (up to v5 as for now) - on `IExceptionHandlerFeature`.

P.S.S. If you're throwing exceptions from the Domain layer to convert them to 4xx code, I'd suggest either using the [khellang's ProblemDetailsMiddleware](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/master/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetailsMiddleware.cs) or returning [DomainResult](https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult/) that can be later converted to `IActionResult` or `IResult`. The later option helps you to achieve the same result without the overhead of exceptions.

Comment: I like this because it's simple and seems to work--just add the code above and you have an instant global exception handler.  Note: If you're using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`, don't forget to remove it for this and similar solutions to work.

Comment: I noticed however that the exception handler was not invoked when throwing from a thread other than the main one.  So for this case I'm using a simple try/catch in my new thread as a workaround (in order to log the exception).  Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Just tested it and it DOES handle exceptions thrown from other threads (and I checked the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`s for this claim). 

Your case is more likely to have another causation (e.g. an exception mapping middleware). Also, pay attention to the registering order of middlewares as emphasised in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388483/968003).

Answer (score 4):

By adding your own "Exception Handling Middleware", makes it hard to reuse some good [built-in logic of Exception Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler) like send an "RFC 7807-compliant payload to the client" when an error happens.

What I made was to extend [built-in Exception handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler) outside of the `Startup.cs` class to handle custom exceptions or override the behavior of existing ones. For example, an ArgumentException and convert into BadRequest without changing the default behavior of other exceptions:

on the `Startup.cs` add:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
```

and extend [ErrorController.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler) with something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("/error")]
        public IActionResult Error(
            [FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var exceptionType = context.Error.GetType();
            
            if (exceptionType == typeof(ArgumentException)
                || exceptionType == typeof(ArgumentNullException)
                || exceptionType == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))
            {
                if (webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    return ValidationProblem(
                        context.Error.StackTrace,
                        title: context.Error.Message);
                }

                return ValidationProblem(context.Error.Message);
            }

            if (exceptionType == typeof(NotFoundException))
            {
                return NotFound(context.Error.Message);
            }

            if (webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                return Problem(
                    context.Error.StackTrace,
                    title: context.Error.Message
                    );
            }
            
            return Problem();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that:

1. `NotFoundException` is a custom exception and all you need to do is `throw new NotFoundException(null);` or `throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument.");`
2. [You should **not serve sensitive error information to clients. Serving errors is a security risk**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-exceptions-to-modify-the-response).

Comment: I did this to return the same structure as netcore:  var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                errorCode = error.ErrorCode,
                errorDescription = error.ErrorDescription,                
            }); 
There are some issues with it though, like e.g. TraceId

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I guess you are returning the ``result`` variable? As you can see in my code, I'm returning a built-in [``BaseController.ValidationProblem``](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or BaseController.Problem. HTTP 400 response

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "File extension is not permitted.",
  "traceId": "|79eb7d85-40b4e4f64c19c86f.",
  "errors": {}
}
```

Comment: Yep, I know. It's a pain to generate it myself and to have e.g. TraceId right, which they change between versions additionally. So there is no way to use ValidationProblem in the middleware. I have the same problem with custom validation of headers: I'd like to return the response in exactly the same way, but since it's not used directly as a parameter I cannot use attribute validation, and in a middleware I would have to "emulate" ValidationProblem json myself...

Answer (score 3):

use middleware or IExceptionHandlerPathFeature is fine.
there is another way in [eshop](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

create a exceptionfilter and register it

```
public class HttpGlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
  public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
  {...}
}
```

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
  options.Filters.Add(typeof(HttpGlobalExceptionFilter));
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!! You saved me!! I was implementing IActionFilter interface instead and it was not catching all the exceptions. Changing it to IExceptionFilter worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## Update ASPNET 8+ with `IExceptionHandler`

In Nov 2023, [aspnet core 8 introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#iexceptionhandler) a new preferred path for exception handling using [**`IExceptionHandler`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.iexceptionhandler).  This is covered on their fundamentals guide on how to [**Handle errors in ASP.NET core**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#iexceptionhandler)

Create a class that implements `IExceptionHandler` which requires a single method `ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync`.  If you have handled the exception, return `true`, otherwise, return `false` to let the next handler attempt if you'd like to chain more than one.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Mime;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

internal class GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> logger,
    ProblemDetailsFactory problemDetailsFactory) : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, 
        Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogError(exception, "Whoopsie");

        var problemDetails = problemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(httpContext, 
            statusCode: StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, 
            detail: exception.Message);

        httpContext.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.ProblemJson;
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)problemDetails.Status;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(problemDetails, cancellationToken);

        return true;
    }
}
```

You'll then need to register this handler via middleware like this

```cs
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();

app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

**Note 1**: You need to call [**`UseExceptionHandler`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandlerextensions.useexceptionhandler) on the app for [**`AddExceptionHandler`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.exceptionhandlerservicecollectionextensions.addexceptionhandler) to work.

**Note 2**: In this example, we return global exceptions via a [**Problem Details**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807) response.  If that's all you wanted to do, you could just add [`builder.Services.AddProblemDetails()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.problemdetailsservicecollectionextensions.addproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-8.0), but creating your own exception handler allows for more customizability.

**Note 3**: This is the prefered route for global exception handling according to microsoft's [guidelines on using Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#exception-filters):

> Prefer middleware for exception handling. Use exception filters only where error handling *differs* based on which action method is called

### Further Reading

- [IExceptionHandler for exception handler middleware #46280](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46280)
- [Create an exception handler in ASP.NET Core 8](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3712741/take-advantage-of-improved-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core.html)
- [ASP.NET Core 8: Improved exception handling with IExceptionHandler](https://anthonygiretti.com/2023/06/14/asp-net-core-8-improved-exception-handling-with-iexceptionhandler/)
- [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Core 8](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/global-error-handling-in-aspnetcore-8)
- [The new way to handle exceptions in .Net 8](https://medium.com/@balibatuhan19/the-new-way-to-handle-exceptions-in-net-8-bb28f9029b02)
- [Handling Errors with IExceptionHandler in ASP.NET Core 8.0](https://medium.com/@AntonAntonov88/handling-errors-with-iexceptionhandler-in-asp-net-core-8-0-48c71654cc2e)
- [How to Use IExceptionHandler to Handle Exceptions in .NET](https://code-maze.com/dotnet-use-iexceptionhandler-to-handle-exceptions/)
- [Handling exceptions in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40614184/1366033)
- [ASP.Net Core exception handling middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58821308/1366033)

Comment: What is the preferred way to specify different IExceptionHandler implementations for different path (routes)?

Comment: @StanT., you can register multiple different `IExceptionHandler`s and simply mark as not handled for the next to check the exception and then throw different types of exceptions in different routes, although Filters are still a good way to provide route level exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle an exception on any particular method is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
...

public ActionResult MyAPIMethod()
{
    try
    {
       var myObject = ... something;

       return Json(myObject);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want set custom exception handling behavior for a specific controller, you can do so by overriding the controllers `OnActionExecuted` method.

Remember to set the `ExceptionHandled` property to true to disable default exception handling behavior.

Here is a sample from an api I'm writing, where I want to catch specific types of exceptions and return a json formatted result:

```
    private static readonly Type[] API_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS = new Type[]
    {
        typeof(InvalidOperationException),
        typeof(ValidationException)           
    };

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);

        if (context.Exception != null)
        {
            var exType = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (API_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS.Any(type => exType == type || exType.IsSubclassOf(type)))
            {
                context.Result = Problem(detail: context.Exception.Message);
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }  
    }
```