# ASP.Net Core Error JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm playing a bit with ASP.NET Core. I'm creating a basic webapi.
I'd like to show a JSON error when there is a problem.

The printscreen shows want I want on my screen.
The only problem is that it's send with a statuscode of 200.

[image: PrintScreen]

```
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
    return Json(NotFound(e.Message));
}
```

I could solve it by doing this:

```
return NotFound(new JsonResult(e.Message) {StatusCode = 404);
```

But I don't like this because now you can specify statuscode 500 with a NotFound.

Can someone put me in the correct direction?

Sincerely,
Brecht

Comment: The second piece of code is the correct way to do it. You "could" specify a 500 as the status code but why would you, you are in control of the api.

Comment: You don't have to set `StatusCode` on the `JsonResult`. The `NotFound` method is already doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you do something like `return NotFound(e.Message);`

Or you might have your own error document format and go for `return NotFound(new ErrorDocument(e.message));`

If you have to return with a JsonResult then go for something like the following:

```
return new JsonResult(YourObject) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound };
```

Now you have full control over response format and your status code too. You can even attach serializer settings if need be. :)

Comment: If I do return NotFound(e.Message); then the error message is displayed as plain text because e.Message is a normal 'string'. My other errors that check the ModelState are in JSON. And it like to have consistency.

I created now and class for making errors. I'll post my new solution seperated. Thanks for showing me the way. I was to busy using NotFound(). It totally forgot about just using 'new JsonResult' as return

Comment: I understand the modelstate checks. If you want a better hand on this, I'd suggest you to use an Exception Filter described a bit about [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html#server-exception-handling).

Then all you ever have to worry about is throwing a proper exception and your controllers would look nice without the global try-catch block surrounding the main code. Just a thought.

And yes, error consistency is a good thing. :)

Comment: Thank you for posting that link. I will check that out!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT: Found a much better solution here on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935583/2961887)

Thank you Swagata Prateek for reminding me to just use a `return new JsonResult()`. I did solve me problem on this way.

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; }
    public int StatusCode { get; }

    public Error(string message, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        Message = message;
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
    }
}    


[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
       return Ok(_manager.GetPokemon(id));
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
       var error = new Error(e.Message, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
       return new JsonResult(error) {StatusCode = error.StatusCode};
    }
}
```