# how to return error in an action that is returning a List<T> type via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an action method which is called by javascript on the front-end using $.getJSON(path) which looks something like below in order to populate a dropdownlist:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public List<SelectListItem> GetSomeList(int cId)
        {...}
```

I now need to modify it so that I can return some custom logic based errors based on certain conditions. What's the best way to go here? Should I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360139/asp-net-core-return-json-with-status-code) and go with IActionResult? Please note my question is more specific to Core MVC and not Web API.

Comment: To return exception/error messages as JSON, the answer is yes, you need to change return type to `IActionResult` and put `return new JsonResult(...)` containing error message you want to show on successful AJAX callback.

Comment: thank you. if you respond with an answer, i'll mark it as such.

Comment: I found a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353016/asp-net-core-error-json. You can adjust the error message and status code of the response based from provided solutions there.