# How to handle custom error in .NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to asp.net core and C#, sorry if my question sounds dumb, below is my code:

```
//startup.cs
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error.html");

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
        await next();
     });
     app.Run(context => {
        throw new Exception("Something has gone wrong");
     });
}
```

we can see that the last middleware throws an exception, so I expects to see my custom `error.html` page to be displayed but I still see "Hello" on the page and there is no `error.html` content, how come?

Comment: Since you want to serve a static error page [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765573/how-to-use-useexceptionhandler-in-the-mvc-startup-without-redirecting-the-user) question might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom error page uses the above configuration.

`context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");` can block `HttpHeaders`, it sets `HttpHeader._isReadOnly` to `true`, and any subsequent operations on `HttpHeader` are invalid. So only Hello will be displayed.

If you delete the code, you will find that you still cannot reach the Error page.

That because when an exception occurs, it will take the route `/errors.html` to reach the corresponding custom error page.

If an exception occurs in the `mvc`, it can be reached normally; But when an exception occurs in the `middleware`, On the way to the custom error page, we pass the abnormal middleware again, so that the custom error page also produces an exception.

This is why the custom error page cannot be displayed.

If you want to throw a `middleware` exception, the easiest way is to use `redirect` instead of `ExceptionHandler`:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Something has gone wrong");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
                context.Response.Redirect("/error.html");
                await next();
            }
        });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm still confused, as you mentioned " On the way to the custom error page, we pass the abnormal middleware again", which abnormal middleware you mean? and how can another exception occur?

Comment: This means that if the middleware is abnormal, it will pass through the abnormal middleware again on the way to the custom error page.

Comment: but when an exception is thrown, it already interrupts the flow. and what's the abnormal middleware in my case?

Comment: You can try it, write the exception in mvc, it will succeed to your error page, and an exception will appear in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the error page middleware. Try:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Also take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for better explanation.