# Exception from EF not caught in middleware

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-core

I have a global middleware handling the exceptions thrown by the application. It works as supposed to except for operations failing at the DB level. When I have a problem that Entity Framework reports (due to flawed config in *Context* definition or other DB related operations), the exception won't report, not even when I step through the execution during debugging.

Instead, this (to me confusing and frustrating) phenomenon arises. Executing the (correct and now working) code below, simply leaves the service, moving the yellow arrow to the controller's return statement and then exists the request reporting *200 OK* to Swagger (although with no data).

```
Thing[] output = Context.Things
  .Include(a => a.SubThings)
  .Where(a => a.Id == id)
  .ToArray();
```

Please note that the sample above **does work** and there's no issue **unless** I make a mistake elsewhere. For instance, I made a boo-boo changing the domain model's `List<SubThing> SubThings {get;set;}=[]` to `IEnumerable<SubThing> SubThings {get;set;}=[]` (which eliminates the capacity of adding the elements to the set) and `SubThing[] SubThings {get;set;}` (isn't allowed for navigation collections). (NB. I know why those errors occur and I'm **not** asking how to resolve them. It's just background info for the question.)

First after (too extensive) debugging, I discovered the issue. Then, surrounding the failing operation by try-catch, exposed me to the error.

```
try
{
  Thing[] output = Context.Things
    .Include(a => a.SubThings)
    .Where(a => a.Id == id)
    .ToArray();
}
catch(Exception exception) { ... }
```

It confuses me and I feel I'm missing something. My impression was that the middleware (registered as the outermost scope) will intercept everything. The failing operation is performed within the request, hence passing a bunch of others, "inner'er" middlewares. From my perspective, it looks like EF expcetions get a fast lane out of the application.

Googling the issue led to info on how to set up the middleware and how to correct incorrectly configured ones. I've checked them all just in case but nowhere did I notice any info other than confirmation that I followed the standard procedures.

It's also weird that Swagger reports *200 OK* instead of *500 Internal Server Error* on this

```
catch(Exception exception) { throw; }
```

but handles perfectly well this

```
catch(Exception exception) { throw new DedicatedCustomException(); }
```

However, my question is specifically if I actually must use the explicit try-catch strategy instead of having an implicit error management for all bad things. It has an impact on the code base size if I have to repeat the try-catch explicitly in every call to DB.

Comment: This won't even compile. The result of `Where` is an `IQueryable<T>`, not a `T[]`. This won't even run, much less throw exceptions. If something runs, it's older code without that part

Comment: And if you split query creation and materialization, exceptions could be thrown on materialization, too.

Comment: The question's snippet produces the compilation error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Thing>' to 'Thing[]`, as this [fiddle shows](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iKHsZc). Post actual  code that compiles, runs and reproduces the issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using extension methods but I see how it can be confusing. However, like I tried to point out (sorry for not emphasizing sufficiently), the issue is due to the domain model not being a list but an enumerable (lacking adding capacity) or an array (not being allowed in the navigation). The issue I'm addressing is the error from EF that won't show unless explicitly try-catch'ed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question (with `.ToArray()`) for clarity. Thanks for remarking on the lack thereof. :()

Comment: Is the exception thrown on application start up, rather than when a EF query is called?
If so, it may be that the EF set up is happening before your middleware is registered correctly?

Comment: @PhilGolding I agree with your statement. However, what I'm puzzled by is the fact that **while debugging**, I get no exception thrown in my face (middleware or not, I'm debugging the entire application, right?) simply being ushered out to the invoking method and, then, controller - **unless** I add an explicit try-catch. I fail to understand why I'm required to try-catch it in order to see it in VS.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other exception handling in the application? like exception filters or some decorator class to catch and eliminate db exceptions.

Comment: @sa-es-ir Yes. I'm positive. I suspect it's due to some side effect of a setting in VS. However, that would imply that executing in the console (which I do) would then expose the crash. But it won't...

Comment: Strange! Any specific settings when adding DbContext to DI?

Comment: @sa-es-ir Nope. Vanilla stuff, same behavior. It's not EF, I suspect. It's everything that it's not thrown in my own code.

Comment: If you use  a "repository pattern" in your "calls to the DB" then your relevant "try ... catch" blocks will all be in the "same place". Use partial classes if necessary; for "DB context code" returning enunerables; or even "extending" entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that having try-catches everywhere not ideal, and should be avoided, unless it makes sense in your design to do so (for example, a 5 step process with a try-catch around each of the 5 steps).

You can configure global exception handling as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615253/2413712).

Comment: How is it different from my middleware that catches the errors? It seems that the post you linked to applies the default error management middleware while I'm applying my own, custom made. Regardless of which, the exception should report in the debug mode in the usual manner. For some reason it doesn't.

Comment: You mean it's not pausing on the exception?  I have suspected recently that the version of EF I am using is deferring execution in some new, magic tricky way.  Are you using async/await?  Also, I have noticed that whichever code file (or perhaps namespace) an EF Linq expression is written in affects how EF compiles/translates those expressions - what specifically do you have in your extension methods, and are they in the same project?

Comment: Is the issue limited to EF, or do you witness the same, unexpected behavior(s) when throwing an error like `throw new Exception("hello");`

Comment: It's limited to EF (and possibly other cases as well) but not with a generally thrown exception in my own code. It's like code I wrote will report an exception in the debug mode as supposed to and any exception thrown by other packages I'm using but not created, get "silenced" (unless I explicitly set a try-catch around them.

Comment: I've eliminated my extension methods and, while using async, I can't see how that's affecting. It's simply like exceptions not thrown by me, won't report (unless explicitly caught).

Comment: I just had the exact same issue using Stripe's NuGet package - where I was using an expired webhook secret, their package was throwing an error and the debugger wouldn't break on it.  I tried going to Tools => Options => Debugging "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain..." and even tried loading symbols from NuGet Symbol Server - and the debugger still won't break on the thrown exception.  I also tried resetting VS.  It may be an issue with VS, which is far from unheard of.  For my situation, this is limited to debug/design time, so it at least is not a production issue.

Comment: I guess it's going to be one of those weird thing nobody cares enough about to actually resolve. And as you point out, it does present the exception in PRD so it "kind of works". Please add the jist of your latest comment (the setting in VS) to the answer and I'll grant you the bounty. Good enough.   :)