# Handling exception in asp.net core for certain exception type?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

I have asp.net core application. To handle exception i am using one of the extension method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics`

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

so when error occurs user gets redirected to error page.

I wanted to know how do i redirect user to certain page based on exception type? something like

```
if( exception is NotAuthorizedException)
{ 
    // redirect to "Home/NotAuthrozied"
}
else
{
  // redirect to "Home/Error"
}
```

How do i handle this inside `app.UseExceptionHandler()` method?
I have already looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) but couldnt find anything. I am also trying to avoid creating custom middleware to handle exception.

Comment: Curious, what are you using for authentication/authorization in your app? If you use Identity, that will handle this for you when you use the Authorize attribute.

Comment: As you may see `UseExceptionHandler` considers only about `ExceptionHandlingPath` (you can check it in its source code). So just use custom middleware, it's pretty easy.

Comment: @R.Richards we have external authentication provider using OpenID connect. so when user authenticated by this external provider, the application also checks if the user exists the application database, if not then throws exception.. in such case I need to redirect user to not authorized page

Answer (score 1):

There was another discussion for the [exception handling using the middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling) approach. The one you are seeing is redirect/route approach however you have other approach such as filter/attribute/global exception