# MapSpaFallbackRoute on Startup ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an Areas on `Net Core App` named `Admin`, on `MapSpaFallbackRoute` setting on startup, I want to set like this,

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
      routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
      name: "spa-fallback-admin",
      defaults: new { area="Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
```

is this the correct way to define `MapSpaFallbackRoute`? I doubt `MapSpaFallbackRoute` have attributes *area*, 
I have been try this, and my apps return 404(not found).
so, what the correct way to define `MapSpaFallbackRoute`, I want using HomeController on Admin area, with Index action

It is my complete code, I want to request with path admin, controller on admin areas should be handle that.

```
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/admin"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback-admin",
                defaults: new { area="Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe it will give you some light on it: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973

Comment: thanks, but i doesnt found what I looking for,  and i doesnt want handle that on angular,
do you any idea how doing that? access controller on some areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `MapSpaFallbackRoute` does is allows defining default values for route parameters to handle 404 cases.

Now to your question: yes, [MVC routing (both attribute/convention) supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) `{area}` as route parameter and so you can write above code to define a default value.

You didn't show your routing setup, so I assume that your main problem is that you haven't specified `{area}` parameter in your route template.

For example, if consider convention routing, the following should work:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
           routes.MapRoute("default", "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
           routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
             name: "spa-fallback-admin",
             defaults: new { area="Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

---

For updated question:
Try to use `.UseWhen` instead of `.MapWhen`:

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/admin"), builder =>
{
```

Comment: I have been updated my question, I added some detail about my code, your solution still not working on me, am I missing something?

Comment: @RipasFilqadar please check update. To be honest I don't know why it works in this way and have created a [separate SO question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49690615/2833802)

Answer (score 0):

after searching for this issue I realize Dotnet core 3 doesn't support `MapSpaFallbackRoute` method so to fix this problem you should add the Spa package manually use this command on your terminal Dotnet

> add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices --version 3.1.16

you can check the version at this link

[NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices)