# Exception handling in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-core, flurl

I'm looking for some guidance on how to best handle exceptions in asp net core. Based on [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) docs from microsoft I've setup the UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects middleware. This works for things such as 404's. However for API requests within my code that return exceptions this doesn't work. So following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters) doc I've setup an exception filter. This kinda works and this is where I'm looking for help.

I have the following code in a class library so it can be re used elsewhere. A mini wrapper for my api. I'm using Flurl to construct the request. My viewModelBuilder calls GetAll.

```
public async Task<List<TableDto>> GetAll(int branchId)
{

    var result = await _baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("/v1/Table/GetAll").WithOAuthBearerToken(await _authenticationManager.GetToken()).GetJsonAsync<List<TableDto>>();
    return result;
}
```

If GetAll throws an exception then the following exception filter comes into play.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {

        // ex.Call.Response.StatusCode // This works with the original exception but not here
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            // Always 200
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do different things based on the exception status code. So for a 401 or 404 I would like to show an access denied screen or a login screen and then for other errors maybe just a general error screen. However context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode is always 200.

1. Is this the right way to go about doing this? The [error handing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#aspnet-mvc-error-handling) suggests that middleware is better but I'm not sure if its referring to this use case as I could only get it working for 404s.
2. How do I get the correct status code in a exception filter?

I know that if I put a try catch around the original GetAll as below

```
try
{
    var result = await _baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("/v1/Table/GetAll").WithOAuthBearerToken(await _authenticationManager.GetToken()).GetJsonAsync<List<TableDto>>();
    return result;

}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    if (ex.Call.Response != null)
    {
        if (ex.Call.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}
```

then in the exception filter I can do the following

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is ForbiddenException)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and then I can do specific things for specific exceptions however thing means I have to try catch every call and voids the point of the global exception filter. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
M

EDIT

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935583/909809) answer here I could write a custom middleware and I quickly did that but I'm still stuck with the same problem of not being able to check for a 401 or 403 and only being able to get access to custom exceptions that have been throw. If I can access the status code then I think both solutions will work

Comment: Just as a side-note, it looks like you're making redundant calls to `GetToken` in each of your code samples. I suspect you want to pass the `token` you've captured in the first line when you call `WithOAuthBearerToken` in the second.

Comment: @ToddMenier Yes, copying fail, will edit and fix. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just let `FlurlHttpException` bubble up to your filter and put your code that inspect it there? Then at least in this case you can avoid wrapping "everything" in a try/catch.