# Globally capture the program exception error and write to a file in asp.net core 2.1 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I, am trying to create a global exception handling service for execution error not a http status error in asp.net core 2.1 web api and write to a file.

Tried few options like

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add(typeof(GlobalExceptionFilter));
            })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
```

**Exception Class**

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            String message = String.Empty;

            var exceptionType = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (exceptionType == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
            {
                message = "Unauthorized Access";
                status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(NotImplementedException))
            {
                message = "A server error occurred.";
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(MyAppException))
            {
                message = context.Exception.ToString();
                status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            else
            {
                message = context.Exception.Message;
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;

            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = (int)status;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            var err = message + " " + context.Exception.StackTrace;
            response.WriteAsync(err);
        }
    }
```

But it never coming to the errors.I tried with debugging but never hit the debugging code.

can anyone please let me how to log the global error on file.

found some of the solution from this solutions
https://blog.elmah.io/error-logging-middleware-in-aspnetcore/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core-webapi/

[ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried serilog? I use [serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) with MongoDb [sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks).