# Why is my GlobalExceptionFilter not working on NET.Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement GlobalExceptionFilter in NET Core WEB API.
This my filter code:

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public GlobalExceptionFilter(ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        this._logger = logger.CreateLogger("Global Exception Filter");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        String message = String.Empty;

        var ex = context.Exception;

        TypeSwitch.Do(ex,
                TypeSwitch.Case<ArgumentException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; }),
                TypeSwitch.Case<ArgumentNullException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; }),
                TypeSwitch.Case<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; }),
                TypeSwitch.Case<KeyNotFoundException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound; }),
                TypeSwitch.Case<DivideByZeroException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed; }),
                TypeSwitch.Case<QueryFormatException>(() => { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed; })
            );

        HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var err = new ErrorPayload()
        {
            Data = data,
            StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
            Message = ex.Message,
            StatusCode = (int)statusCode
        };
        response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(err));
    }
}
```

This is my initializing code in

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc( config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(typeof(GlobalExceptionFilter));                    
        }
    );
}
```

And i'm testing the error handling in this controller method

```
[HttpGet("{idCliente}")]
public IActionResult GetCliente(int idCliente)
{
    throw new QueryFormatException("My Custom Exception");
}
```

Any ideas? thanks!

**UPDATE**

Well, I have to admit that I asume that wasn't working because Postman shows me connection error instead of MethodNotAllowed of NotFound (404). As suggested i examine the debug and the status response and was actually expected value.

Comment: You described what you have but no the debug results, we can’t know exactly what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @MauricioAtanache, how can I describe debug result? Will you help me doing that?

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging your application? Is the exception filter ever executed?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: I believe you still have to register the filter in DI `services.AddScoped<GlobalExceptionFilter>();`

Comment: @Brad You don’t need that with a type filter (i.e. when adding a type to the filter collection). You only need to register it when using a service filter.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exception-filters) say (last section)

> Prefer middleware for exception handling. Use exception filters only
>   where you need to do error handling differently based on which MVC
>   action was chosen. For example, your app might have action methods for
>   both API endpoints and for views/HTML. The API endpoints could return
>   error information as JSON, while the view-based actions could return
>   an error page as HTML.

In your case, if the application only serving API:s then use the exception middleware implementation instead. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935583) a good example of one

Comment: Thank you for that

Comment: Even if this is the accepted answer, note that it does not really answer the question. Using exception filters is certainly not wrong and should generally work.