# How to set a custom json IIS error messages in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 (API) application running in Azure Web App.

My application errors follow a standard json structure. When there is an error (for example a 500) in IIS, it returns a xhtml page with the description of the error.

How can I set Azure Web App, or my application, so that on IIS errors, it returns a json string defined by me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise you to configure a custom exception handling middleware. See here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling

Comment: @Riscie Thanks. I have custom exception handling middleware, but these are not application errors but IIS (server) ones.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this method to achieve this: `IApplicationBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects()`

Here is a sample for your reference:

We can create Controller to handle the error output:

```
 [Route("Home/Error/{statusCode}")]
 public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
 {
        JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new object());
        return jsonResult;
 }
```

Then We can use it in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` as below:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");
```

Hope this would be helpful to you.