# How can I redirect a user when a specific exception is cought with ASP.NET Core 2.2 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a project that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework.

The application throws a custom exception when something unexpected happens.

For example, if the app can't find a default setting in the database, it throws `ApplicationIsNotSetupException()`. This exception indicates that the admin did not install the project using the installation process as they should. Therefore, I want to direct them to the installation controller. (i.e, SetupController.Install())

How can I redirect the user to s specific route if the `ApplicationIsNotSetupException()` was caught?

Comment: If something isn't set up, I'd try to detect that when the application is first started. Fail fast.

Comment: The design decision is questionable, but it should be easy to do when you look up middleware.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can see the redirection being questionable. What about redirecting to a special error page?

Comment: An average user should _not_ be sent to a setup page. An admin shouldn't need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
// This should be before app.UseMvc
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (ApplicationIsNotSetupException)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/setup/install");
    }
});
```

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38630076/6683525), there are some good answers there too.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert your code into try/catch:

```
try {...yourCode...}
catch (Exception ex)
{
if (ex is ApplicationIsNotSetupException)
..Do what ever you want..
else 
...
}
```

than, everytime it will catch the exception you want it will go into the if loop