# ASP.NET Core startup exceptions handling

Tags: asp.net-core

When the code in the startup class throws, ASP.NET Core catches the exception instead of letting it fall through behind the `IWebHost.Build` call.

The app consequently does start but only serves an error page.

So how do I react to a problematic startup if I don't get to catch the exception myself?

Please don't tell me I need to catch it in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: You can follow this [pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935583/7177029)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee This is about startup.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown in the `ConfigureServices()` or `Configure()`

Comment: `ConfigureServices` for now, but really the problem arises for both.

Comment: Why can't you catch it in `startup.cs` ?

Comment: Can you chain the `CaptureStartupErrors()` method to `IWebHost.Build()` call in `Program.cs` like this: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).CaptureStartupErrors(false)`

Comment: @John Better you can log the exception to a text file. Is there any problem of doing so?

Comment: Technically, this is something that belongs in your CI/CD pipeline. If you had even a single integration test, you'd fail before you made it to release.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes, ASP.NET Core doesn't tell me that there was an exception. So I can't react and log anything.

Comment: @John What does Yes mean here? Please make it clear. :)

Comment: @ChrisPratt It can also fail because the configuration changed.

Comment: Essentially, the point is that try/catch is all you've got. An ASP.NET Core app is just a console app with a lot of functionality plugged in. However, at the level of `Program.cs` and even `Startup.cs`, you're still at a very basic console app level. There's no grand exception handling middleware goodness and such, yet.

Comment: The configuration is *also* supposed to be part of your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @ChrisPratt And ASP.NET shouldn't just swallow exceptions in `IWebHost.Build` when it insists to have my startup code to be in a class that it calls. I don't want anything fancy, I want the exception to fall through.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Great, that works!

Comment: @ChrisPratt I agree that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Essence of the comment thread above: do not call

```
builder.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
```

in your `Program.CreateWebHostBuilder` method.