# WebAPI exception return type object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am returning a Custom object when WebAPI call is success and in failure.How to convert to proper response object on client side for this WebAPI? In case of an exception.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<MyRespObject> PostTest([FromBody] MyPostObject obj)
    {
        try
        {

            MyRespObject response = SomeMethod(obj);

            return this.ToActionResult(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return this.ToActionResult(this.LoadMyRespObject(ex));
        }
    }

    protected ActionResult<TResponse> ToActionResult<TResponse>(TResponse response)
    where TResponse : IResponse
    {
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case ResponseStatus.Success:
                return this.Ok(response);
            case ResponseStatus.InvalidRequest:
                return this.BadRequest(response);
            case ResponseStatus.NotFound:
                return this.NotFound(response);
        }

        return this.StatusCode(500, response);
    }
```

In case of an exception how to convert ex to MyRespObject on the client side? I am generating client using autorest for the API?

Comment: In case of an exception. --- I would suggest you to add exceptionhandler  middleware rather than creating explicit error response. This is the standard approach in using asp.net core web api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return Type change to

> HttpResponseMessage

then client side can Check the status of Data

your code will be

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostTest([FromBody] MyPostObject obj)
{
    try
    {
    ResponseModel _objResponseModel = new ResponseModel();
        MyRespObject response = SomeMethod(obj);

        return this.ToActionResult(response);

    _objResponseModel.Data = response;
            _objResponseModel.Status = response.Status;
            _objResponseModel.Message = "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        _objResponseModel.Data = null;
            _objResponseModel.Status = false;
            _objResponseModel.Message = "failed";
    }
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _objResponseModel);
}
}  
  public class ResponseModel
{
    public string Message { set; get; }
    public bool Status { set; get; }
    public object Data { set; get; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert to proper response object on client side for this WebAPI? In case of an exception.**

Thats where middleware comes into picture. Below is the general approach you need to follow which will handle the request efficiently in case of error as well.

- Define **ErrorHandlingMiddleware** which is a async custom class .
- Then register this class as middleware in Startup.cs ,so that each and every request will pass through this middleware.
- In case of error ,write a model generally like this

  ```
    Class Error { 
           int errorCode {get ;set;}        
           string message {get ;set;}
     }
  ```

  so you can modify this class as well for more properties like hint etc.
  Below links have more clear and good explanation.

https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/

[ASP.NET Core Web API exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling)