# Handle SignalR Exceptions in Middleware in .Net Core 2.2 Web API Project

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, signalr, middleware

I'm Working on the .Net Core 2.2 Web API Project.
I have handled thrown exceptions by creating Middleware by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling) post

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionHandleMiddleware));
```

I'm catching exceptions thrown from catch like below,

```
try{
    .....
}catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

It is working fine for requests coming through Web API Calls.

Then I Created Another Layer for SignalR,
Also Added Middleware to its Startup.cs But it is not catching the exceptions thrown in this layer.

So, I guess middleware is working only for Request-Response Pipeline. SignalR is creating Persistent Connection with Client by choosing protocol on its own. So it is not catching it.

So, Is there a way to catch exceptions in Middleware Or Suggest any other better way to handle it.

Thanks in Advance.