# Asp.Net 5/Core app.UseExceptionHandler() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net5

I have in startup

(UPDATE: the solution was to move UseRouting under the /api/error routes)

```cs
app.UseRouting();

if (env.IsDevelopment()) {               
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/error/error-local-development"); 
    SwaggerConfig.Configure(app);              
}
else {             
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/api/error/error");
}

 app.UseCors();
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseDefaultFiles();
 app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); 
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<ResultHub>("/hubs/resultHub");
            });


            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
            });
```

But when `throw new Exception()` in a controller action, the Error controller Methods are never called.

```cs
[Route("api/error")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class ErrorController : OwnBaseController
{
    public ErrorController(IApplicationUserService applicationUserService, ILogger<ErrorController> logger, IDiagnosticContext diagnosticContext) : base(applicationUserService, logger, diagnosticContext)
    {
    }

    [Route("error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return Problem(); 
    }

    [Route("error-local-development")]
    public IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment([FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
       var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
       return Problem(
            detail: context.Error.StackTrace,
            title: context.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen then? I mean is the app crashes or do the exception appears in the log? or xyz?

Comment: In debug modus i see on the manual "throw exception" serilog logging "an exception of type xx occured in xxx.dll but was not handled in user code", it then jumps to the lines line of my testmethod of my test controller and returns a 500.

Comment: Where did you put the `UseExceptionHandler` calls before or after the `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`?

Comment: after app.UseRouting()

Comment: Please try to register them before. These could be the very first method calls in the `Configure`.

Comment: You are right. That was it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It might seem strange but ordering does matter.

`UseExceptionHandler` and `UseRouting` are both registering middlewares under the hood.

The firstly registered will be the outer most middleware. So, if one of the inners throws an exception the outer can catch and handle it.

[image: middleware ordering]
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index/_static/middleware-pipeline.svg?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

MSDN has some warnings about this, for example:

- [Handle Errors in ASP.NET Core's UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute)

> If an endpoint within the app is specified, create an MVC view or Razor page for the endpoint. Ensure `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` is placed before `UseRouting` so the request can be rerouted to the status page.

- [ASP.NET Core Middleware's Middleware order section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order)

> `UseExceptionHandler` is the first middleware component added to the pipeline. Therefore, the Exception Handler Middleware catches any exceptions that occur in later calls.

Comment: I was really hoping this simple solution would have fixed my case. My called to UseExceptionHandler is called first, but the unhandled exception still does not call the error handling controller. There must be other causes for this issue.

Comment: Hi @MatthewMacFarland, could you please share further details in order to be able to help you? (If needed please create a new question and paste here the link)

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, Certainly. I will put my details together and post them soon.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, I discovered my problem while getting ready to post details here. I was running in development mode and the call to `app.UseExceptionHandler()` was only active for when `IsDevelopmentMode = false`. Silly mistake. Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: Hi @MatthewMacFarland it happens to everyone, no worries. I'm glad that you could solve it on your own.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't help for me so, I changed this

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("Home/Error");
```

to this

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

and aldo added an attribute route on the action

```
[Route("/Error")]
public IActionResult Error()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the route name was not the same as the usEexceptionHandler:

I had

```
[Route("/errors")]
public IActionResult Error()
```

and in my program.cs:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
```

both names must be the same for it to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set the exception handler to be called before `UseEndpoints`. If it comes after `UseEndpoints` the handler never gets called.

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

// should be called before UseEndpoints else the exception handler wont be called
app.UseExceptionHandler(); 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```