# How do I handle Exception throw by Intercepter in C#

Tags: c#, exception, autofac

I want to Catch the exceptions thrown by Interceptor, how can I do it?

using autofac6.0.0,.NET 6

Controller>CommandAspect>Commands

The Interceptor can catch Exceptions from Command, but the Controller does not catch Exceptions from the Interceptor.

register

```
builder.RegisterModule<AutofacScanningModule>();
builder.RegisterType<CommandAspect>();
```

AutofacScanningModule

```
public class AutofacScanningModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICommand))))
            .EnableClassInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(CommandAspect)); 
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

CommandAspect

```
 public class CommandAspect : IInterceptor
{
    public CommandAspect()
    {
    }
    public async void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log Output
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

WebController

```
try
{
    type commandType = typeof(CommandClass);
    object commandObject = _serviceProvider.GetService(commandType);
    commandType.GetMethod("SomeCommand").Invoke(commandObject);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //not handled
}
```

Command

```
 public class CommandClass : ICommand
 {
     public virtual void SomeCommand()
     {
       throw new Exception();
     }
  }
```

Exception StackTrace

```
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at Sample.SomeCommand.Find(Record record) SomeCommand.cs:line 42
   at Castle.Proxies.SomeCommandProxy.Find_callback(Record record)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.SomeCommand_Find.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Sample.CommandAspect.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) CommandAspect.cs:line 29
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__127_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext executionContext, Action`1 callb
ack, TState& state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

Resoleved

```
 public class CommandAspect : IInterceptor
{
    public CommandAspect()
    {
    }
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        ProcessInterceptAsync(invocation).Wait();

    }

    private async Task ProcessInterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            var proceed = invocation.CaptureProceedInfo();
            proceed.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log Output
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing async interception right. You have to return `void` from `Intercept` and set the `ReturnValue` to the `Task` result. [See the docs here.](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-async-interception.md).

Your stack trace shows the exception coming from a different thread, hence it's not being caught. If you set up the interceptor right, I bet it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an `ErrorHandling` middleware to handle this. Since middleware is acting outside the controller, the controller doesn't get to see the error.

Have a look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I tried writing app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); but the app terminated after the Exception even in Debug.

Comment: I was talking about using the middleware like, this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling

Comment: to debug can you add a global try catch in your Main method, to see what really is failing.

Comment: It is Web Application. so I tried to write Try Catch in Program.cs , but I couldn't catch it...
Thank you for helpfule

Comment: Even a web application has a main method. Anyways you should be able to catch the exception there. Otherwise if using Visual Studio, you can enable `break on all exception`. This way you would be able to catch them early.